# Chrome redirecting to developer.yahoo.com/yql/console

Tags: google-chrome, virus

I was trying to reach [nintendo.com](http://nintendo.com) and chrome redirected me to  [developer.yahoo.com/yql/console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console) for a few minutes. All other domains were okay. Another person in my office was able to access the site normally while I was getting the bug. The bug was present in incognito mode, so I don't think it's an extension.

My searches seem to point to a rootkit/virus, but I am on Linux Mint. Not that viruses are impossible, but I wasn't able to find any help on the web since all instructions were for windows.

Does anybody have a clue what that is?

Thanks for any help.

edit: I ran rkhunter and it didn't find anything, if that helps.